# laravel redirection error after session out

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, session-timeout, redirect

i am using laravel 4 in my admin section its working fine in normal condition but when session is timeout and i refresh the page than its not redirect properly my admin login path is

```
localhost/project_name/public/admin/login
```

and when i logout its redirect properly but when automatic session out than its not go to to admin/login  its redirect to the followin path

```
localhost/admin/login
```

so can any body tell me the solution for this

Answer (score 2):

@Deepak Goyal,

define a before filter to check that in routes.php, something like:

```
Route::group(["before" => "auth"], function ()
{
//rest of the authenticated routes goes here
}
```

And in the filters.php

```
Route::filter("auth", function()
{

if (Auth::guest()) return Redirect::guest("admin/login");

});
```

Comment: in my rotes.php file i have the code

    Route::group(array('prefix'=>'admin','before'=>'admin-auth'), function(){

 Route::get('/','AdminController@index');
}

and in filter.php file

Route::filter('admin-auth', function(){
 if(Auth::guest() || Auth::user()->usertype == 'client' || Auth::user()->active == 0) return Redirect::to('admin/login?ret='.Request::url());
});

Comment: @Deepak Goyal, create separate filters for Auth::user()->usertype == 'client' and Auth::user()->active == 0.

Comment: @ Deepak Goyal, Just replace if(Auth::guest() || Auth::user()->usertype == 'client' || Auth::user()->active == 0) with if (Auth::guest()) and try

Comment: i have checked this method but problem is still the same than i check the URL problem and i found that when i enter the url like localhost/project_name/public/admin than its working fine but if i use trailing slash like localhost/project_name/public/admin/ than the problem occur so please can you help me in this problem